# How to continue the numbering in rdlc?

Tags: c#, vb.net, rdlc

So I have this matrix in my RDLC form and what I want is to stop the row number at 30 and continue the 31 on the other side of the table

```
    =RowNumber(Nothing)
```

is what I am using in the expression of the column

[image: RDLC Report]

I am using this to make the other table appear

```
    =(RowNumber(Nothing) - 1) Mod 2
```

and as you can see the numbering seems not right it is doubling the numbers

Comment: The post may be tagged with vb, even so I can't understand how the expression produces these ids. Mod with 2 can only results 0 or 1.

Comment: I think you can write the query for row number and then show this row number in the report, my friend. If you need, I can post a sample for query :))

Comment: PLease sir enlighten me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can You Try this One

**Step1:**

- Insert Two Table inside the **RDLC** Report

[image]

**Step2:**

The Design the Page Look like this

[image]

**Step3:**

Model for Student

```
  public class Student
    {
        public int RollNo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Step4:**

In the code behind do with split the data

```
   List<Student> studentModelList = new List<Student>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 60; i++)
        {
            studentModelList.Add(new Student()
            {
                Name = "Student" + i,
                RollNo = i
            });
        }

        ReportDataSource Part1DataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        Part1DataSource.Name = "Part1"; // Name of the DataSet we set in .rdlc
        Part1DataSource.Value = studentModelList.Take(studentModelList.Count/2);

        ReportDataSource Part2DataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        Part2DataSource.Name = "Part2"; // Name of the DataSet we set in .rdlc
        Part2DataSource.Value = studentModelList.Skip(studentModelList.Count / 2);

        reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Report4.rdlc"; // Path of the rdlc file
        reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(Part1DataSource);
        reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(Part2DataSource);
        reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

**Step5:**

Output

[image]

Comment: That is a very impormative answer thank you very much! much respect for you sir